# Cocoa hide menubar without dock

Tags: cocoa, nsapplication

is it possible to hide menubar without hidding dock in cocoa? like Launchpad do.

I have tried

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] setPresentationOptions:0x04];
```

but unfortunately this it doesn't work

maybe there is some private API to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no pubic API for that.

You can also notice that LaunchPad shows the dock if it's hidden. There is probably a private API but I don't know it.